# C++, действительно ли каламбур типизации через void* - запрещен?

Tags: c++, типизация, void

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего именно предназначен бестиповый указатель?

Например:

```
void* p;
```

Позволяет ли указатель данного типа осуществлять каламбур типизации?

К примеру, если в функцию, которая экспортируется из `DLL`, необходимо передать указатель на какие-либо данные, то это, чаще всего, осуществляют так:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void cdecl some_function(void* data)
{
    // ...
    Object*const object = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(data);
    // ...
}
```

Поскольку библиотека ничего не знает о том, что же сокрыто под указателем `data`, библиотека имеет полное право интерпретировать данные так, как посчитает нужным. То есть, `data` может указывать на объект типа, отличного от `Object`, да хоть просто в буфер байтов.

То есть, `some_function()` ниоткуда не вызывается, поэтому данный вызов не подвержен оптимизациям времени компиляции и времени линковки.

Все обстоит совсем по-другому при написании подобной функции вне обособленной библиотеки. Если подобная функция откуда-то вызывается, и компилятор или линкер это видят, они могут применить оптимизации. И если в `data` записывается адрес объекта одного типа, а затем преобразуется в адрес объекта другого типа (несовместимого), тогда возникает неопределенное поведение.

Это действительно так?

PS. На `MSDN` написано следующее:

```
A void* pointer can be converted into any other type of data pointer.
```

И это путает меня еще больше.

Comment: Зачем "каламбур" заводить отдельной меткой? Каламбур - это путаница. Каламбур — литературный приём с использованием в одном контексте разных значений одного слова или разных слов, или словосочетаний, сходных по звучанию. И само слово каламбур запутывает вопрос.

Comment: *"К примеру, если в функцию, которая экспортируется из DLL, необходимо передать указатель на какие-либо данные, то это, чаще всего, осуществляют так:"* - нет, в вашем примере библиотека и вызывающий код должны строго следовать одному и тому же соглашению об интерфейсе, где определяется, что же сокрыто под эти указателем. *"библиотека имеет полное право интерпретировать данные так, как посчитает нужным"* - нет,  не имеет. Вообще у вас тут какая-то каша: вы смешиваете преобразования указателей и разыменование указателей, а еще забываете что библиотеки часто передают в таком виде либо непрозрачны

Comment: Вообще механизм импорта-експорта не совершенный. Линкер соиденяет части программы по имени, не проверяя типы параметров. Только в некоторых "ветках" в суффиксе функции зашит тип (типа борландовские @fn$qi или ещё встречал суффиксы у других фирм). Если при импорте експорте перепутать тип - то не важно, с использованием `void*` или без - на выходе будет сбой - т.е. ничего работать не будет. В хороших библиотеках - параметры функции типизированы.

Comment: Это не только литературный прием, но еще и прием в программировании.

Comment: е пользовательские параметры (т.е. которые потом как-то передаются обратно пользователю, а библиотека с ними ничего не делает), либо дескрипторы (т.е. когда это не указатель).

Comment: Я повсеместно вижу в промышленном коде, который работает десятилетиями, передачу в `DLL` и возврат из `DLL` указателей на что угодно через `void*`.

Comment: конкретно ваш пример демонстирует использование void именно для каламбура типизации (связка С/С++). _ библиотека имеет полное право интерпретировать данные так, как посчитает нужным_ - термин имеет право непонятен) библиотека имеет право, также как и вы имеете право передать туда любой набор цифр вместо указателя, только будет УБ. Поэтому стороны или договариваются, что будет значить void*  или библиотека выставляют наружу структуры данных и от воид* избавляются

Comment: про оптимизации тоже непонятно, если у вас где-то в с++ коде используется воид*, то ни о какой типобезобасности речи не идёт, возможно стат.анализатор ругнётся на такие касты, но компилятор такие касты проверять не будет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, `void *` никак не влияет на запрет каламбуров типизации.

> Поскольку библиотека ничего не знает о том, что же сокрыто под указателем `data`, библиотека имеет полное право интерпретировать данные так, как посчитает нужным. То есть, `data` может указывать на объект типа, отличного от `Object`, да хоть просто в буфер байтов.

Все правильно. Формально, если он указывает не на настоящий `Object`, будет каламбур типизации и неопределенное поведение. На практике, если функция лежит в отдельной библиотеке (или просто в другой единице трансляции, если link-time оптимизация не включена), то компилятор никогда об этом не узнает, и ничего не сломается.

> A `void*` pointer can be converted into any other type of data pointer.

Тут видимо просто имеют в виду, что `void *` можно скастовать к любому другому указателю "на данные" (т.е. не на функции и не на члены класса).

Comment: И почему же `void *` нельзя привести к указателю на функцию?

Comment: @avp Я просто перевел `data pointer` на русский. Насколько помню, стандарт не гарантирует такую возможность, чтобы поддерживать архитектуры, где память для кода и для данных разная, и представление указателей на функции и на данные соответственно разное. Хотя, конечно, на всех нормальных современных архитектурах это не так, и такие касты работают.