# Способы реализации быстрого каламбура типизации в C++?

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие существуют *правильные* способы выполнять в `C++` быстрый каламбур типизации?

Например, в задачах, где очень важна скорость (например, при обработке сетевых пакетов) устоявшимся является способ работы с потоком байтов через указатель на целевой тип:

```
void ProcessPacket(const void*const data, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < sizeof(Packet))
    return;

    Packet*const packet = reinterpret_cast<Packet*const>(data);

    if (packet->Header.Version == 1)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Я знаю, что такой способ нарушает `Правила Строгих Псевдонимов`. Теоретически, это правило можно отключить соответствующим ключом компиляции, но даже в таком случае останется проблема нарушения требований выравнивания целевого типа. Требования выравнивания - более фундаментальная проблема.

Я знаю, что можно использовать для каламбура типизации тот же `memcpy()` или более современный шаблонный вариант преобразования. В основном, компилятор распознает большинство типичных случаев использования `memcpy()` для реализации каламбура типизации, исключая копирование, но даже при учете всего этого код становится объемным и страшным.

Есть ли другие варианты реализации *быстрого* каламбура типизации?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087691/c-действительно-ли-каламбур-типизации-через-void-запрещен#comment1871181_1087691

Comment: @dIm0n, нет, это не совсем то.

Comment: Это ссылка на комментарий, а не на дубликат

Comment: Если созданием буфера, на который указывает указатель `data` управляете вы, то используя [спецификатор alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), вы можете задать необходимое выравнивание для буфера. Таким образом, нарушения требований по выравниванию при касте указателя `data` в нужный вам тип не возникнет.

Comment: @wololo, нет, это не подходит. Что, если нам с какого-то устройства (сетевой карты, роутера и пр.) приходит буфер, в котором лежит множество пакетов? Как выполнить каламбур типизации при анализе таких пакетов так, чтобы не возникли дополнительные издержки на перекладывание данных из буфера в готовые правильные объекты?